# Run a vba function when the worksheet changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that counts the amount of cells that have a specific color in a range and it works great. However if I change that cell's color the function does not update the count. Only when i put text in another cell and hit enter does the function run.

I would like to automate it so that if a change happens the function runs and updates the count. I understand the Worksheet_Change event would be the route to go, but I am not sure how to implement it. For example if i should wrap it in a sub, or if i have a sub that runs the function. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the vba function:

```
    Function Color_Cell_Count(ColorCell As Range, DataRange As Range)
    
        Dim Data_Range As Range
        Dim Cell_Color As Long
        
        Cell_Color = ColorCell.Interior.ColorIndex
        
        For Each Data_Range In DataRange
        
            If Data_Range.Interior.ColorIndex = Cell_Color Then
                Color_Cell_Count = Color_Cell_Count + 1
            End If
        
        Next Data_Range

End Function
```

**Update** -
Using some more Google fu, I'm finding that excel doesn't calculate for a cell color change so the function won't run. To work around that you create an event listener to watch a range of cells, and if a change is done it runs the function. The info is from 2002 so I'm hoping that Excel or VBA has improved since then.

Comment: Use the `SelectionChange` event I'd think. The `Change` event doesn't fire when you change the color of a cell.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the reply. Where about would i use this?

Comment: In a sheet code module.

Comment: @BigBen i understand it goes in a module. I'm not sure how to implement it in the module.

Comment: Not *a module* - a ***sheet*** module, i.e. the code-behind of the worksheet you want to handle events for. Select `Worksheet` from the dropdown at the top-left of the VB editor, then select `SelectionChange` from the dropdown at the top-right of the VB editor; write the code that needs to run when the selection changes in the procedure scope that the VBE automatically creates for you.

Comment: Here is a tutorial of sorts: https://www.brainbell.com/excel/worksheet-change-selectionchange.html  So, for example, if you want to count the colors in B2:B100 that match B1's colour anytime a cell in B1:B100 is clicked you could right click on theSheet tab and select View Code and then make this `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`
`If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B100")) Is Nothing Then`
`Range("B1").Value = Color_Cell_Count(Range("B1"), Range("B2:B100"))`
`End If`
`End Sub`

Comment: Could you share the link to the *Event Listener* solution?

Answer (score 0):

Jerry Jeremiah in the comments pointed me in the right direction. For the sheet module I included a loop to cover the cells where the color is to make it cleaner.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    OpRange = "A2:B200"
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(OpRange)) Is Nothing Then
        For c = 14 To 20
            Range("F" & c).Value = CellColorCount(Range("D" & c), Range(OpRange))
        Next c
    End If

End Sub
```

Then I have a single module outside of the sheet that holds the CellColorCount function. I didn't want to duplicate the function over and over for each sheet, and I wish I didn't have to do that for the code above, its redundant but I will keep messing with that until I figure it out.

Here is the CellColorCount function. I reformatted the name of the function to eliminate some extra characters. Otherwise it is the same as above. It can still be used in a formula with the correct parameters.

```
Function CellColorCount(ColorCell As Range, DataRange As Range)

    Dim Data_Range As Range
    Dim Cell_Color As Long
    
    Cell_Color = ColorCell.Interior.Color
    
    For Each Data_Range In DataRange
    
        If Data_Range.Interior.Color = Cell_Color Then
            CellColorCount = CellColorCount + 1
        End If
    
    Next Data_Range
    
End Function
```

I'm sure I'm going to tweak it as things go on, but this achieved the goal I had in mind of automating a count of cells that contain a specific color.